# angular material button text and icon alignment

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

i have a button like below

```
<button mat-stroked-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" color="primary">
                          My button 
                         <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
                        </button>
```

What i am noticing is that this center aligns the icon and the text. What I want is though to have text towards left and icon towards extreme right. i cannot use mat-icon button as i need the stroked button look.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be setting the padding of the button element to 0, or to any value that satisfies your need, and you will need to play around with the width of the .mat-icon

```
button{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 5px
}

.mat-icon{
    width: 20px;
}
```

[image: Sample resutl]

Comment: Build your custom button